# mysql return amount rows depending on field vlue

Tags: mysql, counter

```
select id,name,total_copies from contacts.
```

that's the select statement. As is it can bring back

The result is

```
1,john,1
2,peter,3
3,sara,2
```

I need it to be

```
1,john,1
2,peter,2
2,peter,2
2,peter,2
3,sara,2
3,sara,2
```

So in a nutshell, if total_copies = 3 it must return the row 3 times, if value is 5 it must return row 5 times etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT contacts.*, n
FROM
  (SELECT n1.n*10+n2.n n FROM
  (SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) n1,
  (SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) n2) numbers
   INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.total_copies>numbers.n
ORDER BY
  id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93e7c/16). An indexed table with numbers should make the query easyer and faster:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n int);    
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

SELECT contacts.*
FROM numbers INNER JOIN contacts
     ON contacts.total_copies>numbers.n
ORDER BY id;
```

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9538f/1).